# Можно ли записать содержимое оперативной памяти на диск?

Tags: linux, память, взлом, ram, posix

Необходимо сделать копию содержимого оперативной памяти. Фактически мы должны сделать скриншот ram и записать его в файл. Я не нашел для этого никаких средств, подскажите каким образом это вообще можно сделать и можно ли?

OS linux само собой
По возможности, хотелось бы это сделать без root прав и не выходя за рамки инструментария стандартной библиотеки си и posix.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/164960/how-do-i-dump-physical-memory-in-linux

Comment: содержимое озу ведь меняется, вам нужно в произвольное время или за промежуток какой-то?

Comment: @Andrew , в конкретный момент времени

Comment: kdump - думаю, то, что вы ищете.

Comment: @Эникейщик 
Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Тем не менее, спасибо - решение хорошее, я приму ответ как верный, если вы его оформите как ответ

Comment: Ваша ссылка про как написать хороший ответ тут неприменима, потому что у меня не ответ, а комментарий, о чем вам прекрасно известно. Оформлять как ответ мне лениво, можете сделать самостоятельно. PS. Да и ресурс тот не такой уж и внешний.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без sudo это совершенно невозможно. Не мучайтесь ищите другие способы взлома!

Comment: `Без sudo это совершенно невозможно` — в такой формулировке звучит абсолютно бредово. ведь ни отсутствие, ни наличие **программы** sudo никак не может ни помочь, ни помешать чему бы то ни было.

Answer (score 1):

Linux предоставляет для этой цели два виртуальных устройства: `«/dev/mem»` и `«/dev/kmem»`, хотя многие дистрибутивы отключают их по умолчанию из соображений безопасности. `'/dev/mem'` связан с физической системной памятью, тогда как `'/dev/kmem'` сопоставляется со всем пространством виртуальной памяти, включая все свопы. Оба устройства работают как обычные файлы и могут использоваться с dd или любым другим инструментом для работы с файлами. 
**Ещё раз - на некоторых(может даже многих) дистрибутивах такого может и не быть**

Так же есть подключаемый модуль ядра [Linux Memory Extractor](https://github.com/504ensicslabs/lime)

Подробнее(источники):

1)Комментарий [Эникейщика](https://user:282277)
2)[Похожий вопрос на SE](https://superuser.com/questions/164960/how-do-i-dump-physical-memory-in-linux)

**PS : всё еще интересует есть ли возможность делать такое без root прав.Если вы знаете ещё решение, поделитесь пожалуйста. Всем огромное спасибо!**

Comment: `есть ли возможность делать такое без root прав` -- естественно, нет. Но в чем поблема (на своей машине) стать рутом?

Comment: @avp

на своей машине  :))

Comment: На своей, напишите `sudo bash` и делайте что хотите

Comment: @avp я имел в виду, что ваше уточнение на своей машине тут ключевое. Конечно, если я пароль не знаю, то машина скорее всего не моя, собственно в эту сторону я копаю

Comment: Тогда копайте в сторону взлома линукса, хакерские ресурсы где-нибудь в даркнете ...